# How can I get main bransh "master"? I can't make new bransh without it. At cmd I get only errors after using commands "git push -u"

Tags: java, git, github

If I use command "git bransh master", it get "Not a valid object name: 'master'". And after using "git push user master", it get "error: failed to push some refs to 'user'".

I can't understand, why my main branch 'master' isn't master.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NZdh.png)

On the picture you cn see, that I don't have main branch 'master' at creating new branch

This is my project on github:
https://github.com/Elizabeth08122000/blogBaigushkina.git

Comment: By the way, if I use command "git checkout -u", my main branch only rename and that's all.

Comment: Your branch url is invalid (not found).

Answer (score 0):

Github decided to [rename the 'master' branch into 'main'](https://www.infoq.com/news/2020/10/github-main-branch/). So new projects do have a 'main' instead of a 'master' branch. Try to check out a main branch.